# What is the randomness of the return value of the malloc function?

Tags: c, random, malloc

I found this code snippet in an old and dusty project:

```
int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(p));           // generate random number
free(p);                                    // free up space
int rand = p%3;                             // get random value in between 0-2
```

Apart from it being bad style and unnecessary as we got srand in the C standard lib, what is the actual randomness of the return value?

While true randomness is not needed in the context it is used, I tested it several times for 99999999 iterations each and for every single test run `rand == 0` was  less often true than both other cases (`rand == 1` and `rand == 2`).

One example:

- `rand == 0`: true 27343746 times out of 99999999
- `rand == 1`: true 36328138 times out of 99999999
- `rand == 2`: true 36328115 times out of 99999999

Comment: it heavily depends on the operating system and default alignment and the concurrent tasks running... You could also look inside the buffer to see which data is in it if you want random garbage.

Comment: Not very random. In MSVC I got `99995906 0 4093`. The same memory is probably allocated most of the time, because you `free` it.

Comment: in addition "The malloc() and calloc() functions return a pointer to the allocated memory that is suitably aligned for any kind of variable". So it will work in a satisfactory way for 3 or 7 but certainly not for multiples of 2 like 2,4,8. what you have here is non-portable code!! get rid of that (besides, not sure that it's more performant that the real random generator at all!)

Comment: This trick is really bad! implicit conversion of a pointer to an integer type should be considered an error. I don't even know if `p%3` should necessarily be positive...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really silly way of getting a random number. Its behavior is extremely dependent on the platform and on what else the application code is doing. For example, if you call it in a loop with no other memory allocation going on, then on many systems `malloc` will keep returning the same block over and over because `free` returns it to the front of the free list, so `p` will be the same each time. On many others, you'll get a cycle eventually as the heap grows to a certain size and then the allocator cycles through a number of slots.

This particular possibility is evidently what's happening in your experiment: you get `rand==0` in 70/256 cases and `rand==1` and `rand==2` in 93/256 cases (apart, presumably, from the first few allocations where the cycle has not been reached yet and the last, partial cycle). I'm not familiar enough with malloc implementations to explain this particular distribution; possibly the control structures used by malloc have a size that's a multiple of 3 which would create a bias modulo 3.

Modulo a power of 2, you'd get a bias on every realistic platform as the return values are guaranteed to be correctly aligned for any type and most platforms have alignment constraints on powers of 2. Or, in other words, a few of the lowest-order bits of `p` are always 0.

`rand` is standard C and, bad as it is on most platforms (don't even think of using it for anything related to security, and even for probabilistic algorithms it often isn't good enough), it would rarely be worse than `malloc` output.

There are probably a few platforms out there where the return value of `malloc` is randomized to make exploitation of bugs such as buffer overflows and use-after-free harder (because the attacker can't predict where interesting objects will be, in the same vein as [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)), but such platforms would have a better random generator API anyway.

Comment: You may think it's silly but OpenSSL for the longest time in order to create a high entropy random number just walked through and accumulated data from the bytes of the heaps of the various processes in the system.

Comment: @NoelC Was that supposed to convince me that it's not so silly, or to reinforce my point? Because the minimum entropy from doing that is zero, reached in common scenarios such as a VM appliance.